# What should I have to kill the Eye of Cthulhu in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I have some OK stuff such as decent weapons and armor, but can you look at this list of what I have and suggest some new stuff I should get and/or improve to kill the Eye of Cthulhu?
List of some stuff I have:

- Gold chestplate and helmet with Iron greaves.
- Healing Potions, Archery Potions, Bowls of Soup, Ironskin Potions, and some "cheap" Potions.
- 9 Hearts of health and 8 Stars of Mana.
- Demon Bow with some Unholy Arrows and Fire Arrows.
- Space Gun.
- Some Grenades.
- Water Bolt spell.
- Phaseblade.

Comment: I usually defeat the Eye of Cthulhu just to get some demonite and gold in the beginning of the game. Often, when I'm geared up better, I defeat him as many times as I can just to farm the money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space Gun, Phase Blade can only be gotten if you have smashed a shadow orb and a meteorite as fallen and mined the Meteor Ore in which case you should have Meteorite Bars which you can get a full set of Meteor Armour.

Demon Bow, unless you mine a crap tones to get the tiniest deposits of Demonite Ore you can't have gotten normally unless you fought the Eye of Cthulhu or the Eater of World which the latter is a harder boss.

other than that you're vastly overpowered to fight it and really there's no point unless your after the trophy it can drop (or some achievement on consoles) because getting Meteor stuff means your in the upper tier of Pre-Hardcore Equipment